# Installing Linux by booting from USB

Tags: operating-systems, linux-mint, boot, bios

I'm trying to install Linut Mint 20.2 MATE but my attempt to boot it from a USB drive has failed miserably.

I downloaded Rufus and set everything up but when I stick the USB in and turn on the computer Windows 10 boots normally. Pressing DEL before that happens brings up the prompt "Enter CURRENT password:". This is an old second hand computer. I've tried:

- Switching USB ports.
- Removing the CMOS battery and putting it back in after an hour.
- Punching in common default AMIBIOS passwords.

The only thing I haven't tried is messing with the jumpers, since I couldn't find the motherboard manual (this is a POS-PIQ57BQ) and they aren't labeled. (Needless to say, this is not my area of expertise.) I can also tell you that there is no option in the Windows boot menu that has anything to do with UEFI and that, when I open msinfo32, under BIOS Mode it says "Herdado" (Brazilian Portuguese) which translates to Inherited.

Could this whole ordeal be bypassed if I burned Linux Mint onto a DVD? I'm worried I'll run into the same problem and it'll be a waste of time and money.

(I do also have a second hard drive which, when connected, makes Windows 7 run. If there's any way I could install Mint on that drive without having to boot from anywhere, do let me know. Should this be a separate question?)

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could try.

Make sure the OS on your usb drive is working.

Enter the bios and change the bootorder to make sure you boot from usb

Many systems now support BBS, showing the bootable devices.

For both you need to hit the correct key (depending on your bios) to enter.
Most often these are the DEL, ESC, F8 or F12 keys.

Further more windows 10 has a feature called `Fast Startup`
(see: https://lifehacker.com/shutting-down-windows-10-doesnt-actually-shut-down-wind-1825532376)
This means that when you shutdown your computer it isn't really shut down.
So when you boot your computer it does just wake up from some suspended state, and of cause won't start from usb.

My guess would be that this is the cause of the problem. So you would have to disable this. (I encountered this problem when installing linus next to windows for someone)
I'm no windows user, but if you search the internet on `windows 10 fast startup` you find lots of explanations how to do this.

Disconnect your windows 10 drive, connect your windows 7 drive and try again.
windows 7 has no `Fast Startup` feature as far as I know.

Comment: When I disconnect both hard drives I'm able to boot from the USB stick. If any HD is connected the computer doesn't let me do that.

Comment: I'm able to press DEL before startup but the BIOS prompts a password, which I don't know and haven't been able to reset.

Comment: I have no experience resetting a bios password but i found this [link](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-reset-remove-clear-or-reveal-cmos-bios-security-password/), mentioning the [CMOS De-Animator 3](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/cmos_de_animator.html) which should be able to carry out a "clear CMOS" procedure under windows.

Comment: You can also try to install linux on your second hard drive using another computer and then move this disk to the computer you want to use it on. Be careful not to install 64 bit linux if the destination computer is 32 bits. Or using uefi if the destination computer uses a legacy bios. But I've had linux installed on an external hard drive and was able to use it on different computers.